# Python script for the minimum distance between two fitted polynomials

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, computational-geometry, polynomial-math

I have two arrays of 3-dimensional points, and I need a function that tells me the minimum distance between one array to the next.

I've tried to use np.linalg.norm to calculate the distance between one point on the curve against every point on the other curve and then take the minimum, but the run time is really long, and it's not very elegant.

As a result, I tried to fit a n-degree polynomial to both arrays and transform them into a polynomial function.

Here's [the link to the polynomial fit](https://storage.googleapis.com/pythonstackflowquestion/PolynomialRegression%20V2.py)

Here's [the link to the rawdata](
https://storage.googleapis.com/pythonstackflowquestion/TestData.csv)

column WB marks separate arrays.

I'm hoping to get a function as such

def spacing(WB1, WB2)
       return (Spacing)

where WB1 is a n by 3 array and WB2 is z by 3 array, and spacing is a n by 1 array.

if I were to say spacing (WB2, WB1)

then I hope to get spacing as a m by 1 array.

Comment: By "that tells me the minimum distance between one array to the next" do you mean the shortest distance between any two points?

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/pythonstackflowquestion/TestData.csv

Comment: https://storage.googleapis.com/pythonstackflowquestion/PolynomialRegression%20V2.py

Comment: @JoeIddon I mean the minimum distance between the two sets of arrays. The question is if I were to give you set A as [a_X1, a_Y1, a_Z1] and set B[b_X1, b_Y1, b_Z1] where A is (m by 3) and B is (n by 3), I'm hoping to get an a array that compares A to B as (m by 1). If I were to compare B to A, the result will be (n by 1).

Comment: An array of points and a curve are virtually two unrelated things. You must be more explicit about what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

From what you say I infer that you are fitting cubic polynomials (in 3D) and want to minimize the distance between two cubic arcs.

If the parametric equations are `P(u)` and `Q(v)` respectively, you want to minimize `|P(u)-Q(u)|²`, which is a polynomial of degree 6 in `u` and `v`. To minimize it in the unit square, you need to consider the values at corners (discrete values), along edges (1D minimization), and inside the domain (2D minimization).

The 2D minimization problem is the hardest. It requires the determination of the solutions of the system

```
P'(u).(P(u) - Q(v) = 0
Q'(v).(P(u) - Q(v) = 0
```

(where `.` is a dot product).

This is an uneasy numerical problem, and I see no real benefit compared to the direct resolution of the initial problem on the two point sets.

I would recomment to organize the points of one curve using a nearest-neighbor search accelerator such as a kD-tree, and compute the shortest distances to all points of the second. By using the acceleration device, you can reduce the complexity from O(N²) to approximately O(N Log N).

---

In computational geometry, the problem of finding the pair of nearest neighbors in a point set is a well-known one, and a worst-case optimal solution in time O(N Log N) is a classic.

In your case you are looking for the closest pair, with the members in two distinct subsets. In computational geometry, this would probably be called the "closest red-black point pair" problem, or similar. I couldn't find a trace of it.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for this. I think you are right, the idea result in something pretty complicated. In the end, I just permutate through every point from one curve another. The kD-tree is a new idea. I will look into that!!